# Cordova "hidekeyboard" event not working in Cordova 5.0

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have added event "hidekeyboard" as follows.

```
document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", function () {
        alert("keyboard hidden");
}, false);
```

This should fire when we hide soft keyboard on mobile device. Normally when we focus input element soft keyboard comes up and it fires **"showkeyboard"** event. Also when keyboard gets hide **"hidekeyboard"** event gets fired. It was working before when I was using **cordova 4.0** but now I **updated the cordova to 5.0** and now it is not working.

Comment: There are no such [events](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events) build it in cordova unless you have installed a plugin like this https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard. If that's the case then the plugin might not be compatible with cordova 5 yet.

Comment: I remember I have not added any plugin. I just google for  event and added it. It was working in in cordova 4.0 but after update it is not working.

Comment: That's true murli,I too am facing same issue,but didn't get solution yet.

Comment: Don`t forget this works only for IOS. But what about Android?

Answer (score 4):

After release of Cordova Android 4.0.0, "hidekeyboard" and "showkeyboard" events were removed.You should use a plugin instead.
You can confirm this [here](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/15/cordova-android-4.0.0.html) (https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/15/cordova-android-4.0.0.html) ,take a look at "Other Changes" section.
**If possible in your case, you can use below script, as "window resize" event gets called when keyboard is shown or hidden.**

```html
window.onresize = function(){
  if($('.footer').css('position') == 'fixed')
 $('.footTab').css('position','relative');
  else
 $('.footer').css('position','fixed');
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady () {
    document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", onHide, false);
    document.addEventListener("showkeyboard", onShow, false);

}
function onHide() 
{
    alert("hide");
}

function onShow() 
{
    alert("show");
}
```

Try adding listeners in Platform ready OR Document ready.

Regards.